# QTimer stops and starts by itself

Tags: c++, events, qt, qt4, timer

Here is how I use QTimer:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->setInterval(1000);
timer->start();
```

Program monitors update() function  and prints the current time in it. Normally it works as expected, it prints time at every second, but when program starts to process other jobs, there would be some breaks like 5 to 8 secs.

[Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimer.html#accuracy-and-timer-resolution) mentions about accuracy issues like 1 ms, obviously I have another problem. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTimer (and all event-base message deliveries) is not interrupt driven. That means you are not guaranteed you will receive the event right when it's sent. The accuracy describes how the event is triggered, not how it's delivered.

If you are not doing threaded process on long job, call [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) periodically during the long process to ensure your slot gets called.

Comment: I guess you mean "QCoreApplication::processEvents()". Class which is the owner of QTimer is derived from QThread. "long process" is mostly I/O and it is owned by a normal class. Then referring to documentation you pointed out "Calling this function processes events only for the calling thread.", I guess I also need to derive my I/O class from QThread.

Comment: Indeed I meant processEvent. Bad C&P skill. :) You should still call it even when the signal is from a separate thread. That's how signal gets delivered across threads. Also be careful that where the function is (in which class) has nothing to do with which thread it will run in. It's up to which thread the function is CALLED from. You can have a member function in QThread and call it from the main thread. It will run in the main thread. The reverse is true too. Placing a function in a "normal" class does not guarantee it being called only from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your other jobs run for several seconds, and there's no event processing during these. You'd need to thread the jobs in order to get the responsiveness you want.